# Add Virtual host in mac using mamp pro

Tags: macos, mamp, virtualhost, mamp-pro

I need to add virtual host in Mac using MAMP Pro.

First step:(Edit hosts in /etc/hosts) like This

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
27.0.0.1 BSDs-iMac.local # added by Apache Friends XAMPP
127.0.0.1   symfony.local   # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!
::1     symfony.local   # MAMP PRO - Do NOT remove this entry!
```

Next Step:(Open MAMP's vhosts file)  and remove `#`

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Next Step: (edit httpd conf)

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Desktop/avinar/my-project/public"
    ServerName symfony.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Last Step add virtual host into mamp pro like this:

[image]

Now when I check Url: `symfony.local` i see this error:

> >
>   Forbidden
>   >
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

When I check this url: `symfony.local/my-projet/public` server work and i see page.

How do fix this problem?!

Answer (score 0):

That virual host may be lacking a `Directory` directive:

```
<Directory "/Desktop/avinar/my-project/public">
    Options -Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If it doesn't work, recursively set `apache` (or however the user may be called) as the owner (or owner group) of `/Desktop/avinar/my-project`.